# Is it possible to ignore Kafka Consumers with certain client versions?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

We have upgraded our Kafka Brokers to `0.10.2.1` and at the same time also updated the log message format version.

But we know from tests that if Kafka Consumer with pre-10 client versions subscribe to the topics in the upgraded Kafka Brokers, it causes very high CPU uptick, causing serious service degradation.

Is it possible for us to setup a configuration in Kafka Brokers itself, such that Kafka Consumer clients with old versions are rejected?

Comment: Why not disable or upgrade the clients? I'm not sure how you'd prevent specific consumer connections of specific version without blocking their IPs from connecting to the host.

Comment: We are not completely in control of the errant clients, so that might be difficult @WilliamHammond

Answer (score 1):

If you were to disable the plaintext port and run with only SSL or SASL authentication then it would prevent any 0.8 or earlier clients from connecting. It would also give the the capability to create individual logins so you would know who's connecting and enable ACLs and quotas.